# Struggling with Google firebase Datasnapshot in Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So im doing a project where i have to get Values from specific places from Google Firebase database and put them into textViews in android studio and ive been trying to get 1 value from 1 place to get an idea how everything works before i try to go any further, so here is what ive been trying to do:

***Database structure:***

```
{
  "Flower" : 100,
  "Flowers" : {
    "Flower1" : 123,
    "Flower2" : 1233,
    "Flower3" : 830,
    "Flower4" : 95,
    "Flower5" : 1,
    "Flower6" : 20,
    "Flower7" : 330,
    "Flower8" : 50
  }
}
```

so with this code im about to show you below my android emulator keeps crashing, but when i change:

`String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();`

to:

`String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);`

It opens up but doesnt show any values from databases in the textview im trying to get them to but also returns a null when i try to show it with line:
`Log.d(TAG, "Value is : "value)`

Its possible that im only blind to my own code since ive been trying to make this work for a long period of time today but **What i have to fix in my code to get value from database into my textView?**

Thank you already for possible help.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5;
    TextView textViewDate1, textViewDate2, textViewDate3, textViewDate4, textViewDate5, textViewDatabase;

    ArrayList<String> listDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String url = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Flower");

        setTextViewIds();
        connectToFmiAndShowResult();

        getData();

    }

    private void getData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                long value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                textViewDatabase.setText("" + value);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


    private void connectToFmiAndShowResult()
    {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {


                    String myResponse = response.body().string();

                    String [] tokensTemp = myResponse.split("<BsWfs:ParameterValue>");
                    String [] tokensDate = myResponse.split("<BsWfs:Time>");

                    for (int i=1; i<tokensDate.length; i++)
                    {
                        listDate.add(tokensDate[i].substring(0, Math.min(tokensTemp[i].length(), 10)));
                        listTemp.add(tokensTemp[i].substring(0, Math.min(tokensTemp[i].length(), 5)).replace("<","").replace("/",""));
                    }

                    String d1 = listDate.get(0);
                    String d2 = listDate.get(1);
                    String d3 = listDate.get(2);
                    String d4 = listDate.get(3);
                    String dLast = listDate.get(listDate.size()-1);

                    String t1 = listTemp.get(0);
                    String t2 = listTemp.get(1);
                    String t3 = listTemp.get(2);
                    String t4 = listTemp.get(3);
                    String tLast = listTemp.get(listTemp.size()-1);

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            textViewDate1.setText(d1 + ":");
                            textViewDate2.setText(d2 + ":");
                            textViewDate3.setText(d3 + ":");
                            textViewDate4.setText(d4 + ":");
                            textViewDate5.setText(dLast + ":");

                            textView1.setText(t1 + "°C");
                            textView2.setText(t2 + "°C");
                            textView3.setText(t3 + "°C");
                            textView4.setText(t4 + "°C");
                            textView5.setText(tLast + "°C");


                        }
                    });
                }
            }


        });

    }


    private void setTextViewIds()
    {
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp1);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp3);
        textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp4);
        textView5 = findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp5);

        textViewDate1 = findViewById(R.id.textViewDate1);
        textViewDate2 = findViewById(R.id.textViewDate2);
        textViewDate3 = findViewById(R.id.textViewDate3);
        textViewDate4 = findViewById(R.id.textViewDate4);
        textViewDate5 = findViewById(R.id.textViewDate5);
        textViewDatabase = findViewById(R.id.textViewDatabase);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I did now. Cant upload normal picture since low reps..

Comment: If you replace he picture with the actual JSON as text, you won't hit this problem. You can easily get the JSON by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Okay thank you for your advice and answer. Hopefully now it is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```

To:

```
long value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
```

And this line:

```
textViewDatabase.setText(value);
```

To:

```
textViewDatabase.setText("" + value);
```

This is needed because your "Flower" property holds in your database a number and not a String. The result in the logcat will be:

```
100
```

**Edit:**

Seeing your [new database schema](https://ibb.co/3f309c6), to print `100`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference flowerRef = rootRef.child("Flower");
flowerRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                long value = task.getResult().getValue(Long.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "value: " + value);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
value: 100
```

Comment: For some reason my application keeps still crashing when i did those changes, any idea why?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question, or here in a comment.

Comment: I edited my post and added those there now.

Comment: Please edit your question again, and show me the exact code that produces this error.

Comment: Okay did add whole MainActivity.java, hope it helps.

Comment: The code from my answer should work unless you have a different database structure. Please also add a screenshot of it, to be 100% sure. Thanks

Comment: https://ibb.co/3f309c6
here it is. I cant add normal images here yet so i had to upload someehwere else

Comment: Please check the code in my updated answer. Does it print `100` right now?

Comment: Not sure if you ment what i just did but i tried something like this: https://ibb.co/7R01374
Very sorry for misunderstanding if i did so, but with like that it still keeps crashing and saying the same in Logcat..

Comment: By changing  long value = task.getResult().getValue(Long.class);
to:
 Long value = task.getResult().getValue(Long.class);
It doesnt give errors but it still returns Null to Logcat as "value: null"

Comment: I just tested myself, with the same code, and the same database structure as yours, and it works perfectly fine. There might be something else in your code. Besides that, `long value = task.getResult().getValue(Long.class);` works also fine too. Have you try it again?

Comment: It seems that it works fine also on my laptop with same code but not on my main computer... no idea what ive done wrong or why or how to fix it but i think the issue has been fixed and another one came along lol. But very much appreciated for the help!!

Comment: If it works on your laptop, should work everywhere, and it means that the problem is solved. Be sure to have the exact same code on your main computer as well.

Comment: If you got another issue, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.